# Ideas to create price range function for a PHP ecommerce website

Tags: php, e-commerce

Any ideas to create a function which will return 5 ranges in an array with starting price and end price. The function needs to create these ranges for a category or brand or any filter used. Many e-commerce websites are already using the price range filter. Right now I am able to create function like this. But here I have to add the steps range. Is there a way that these steps can be automatically based on the overall price range for that category.

```
function price_range($category_id=0, $step=199)
{   
$output = '';
$return = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = ".$category_id;
$query .= " ORDER BY PRICE";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result)
{
    return FALSE;
}
else
{
    if((mysql_num_rows($result) == 0))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 

            $prices = array($row['price']); 
        } 
        $ranges = array(); 

        foreach($prices as $p) 
        { 
            $index = floor($p / $step);  
            if(isset($ranges[$index])) 
                $ranges[$index]++; 
            else 
                $ranges[$index] = 1; 
        } 

        for($i = 0; $i <= max(array_keys($ranges)); $i++) 
        { 
            //$output = "(<a href=\"?start=" . ($step * $i) . "&end=" . ($step * ($i + 1)) . "\">" . ($step * ($i + 1)) . " - " . ($step * $i) . "(" . $ranges[$i] . ")<br>";
            $return[$i]['start'] =  ($step * $i);
            $return[$i]['end'] =  ($step * ($i + 1));
            $return[$i]['product_count'] = $ranges[$i];
        }  
    }
}
return $return;
}
```

Comment: I'm about going to sleep, so I can't create a complete answer. But did you already think of something like first run a query to find the `MIN` and `MAX` price. Then `(maxprice - minprice)/5` to find the ranges for creating the array ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT
   (MAX(PRICE) - MIN(PRICE)) / COUNT(product) AS step
FROM
   products
WHERE
   category = ?
GROUP BY
   category
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the range function.

```
$steps = 5;
$delta = floor((max($prices) - min($prices)) / $steps);
$price_steps = range(min($prices), max($prices), $delta);
```

$price_steps becomes:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  float(0)
  [1]=>
  float(20)
  [2]=>
  float(40)
  [3]=>
  float(60)
  [4]=>
  float(80)
  [5]=>
  float(100)
}
```